# jQuery - How to mathematical in animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

My JavaScript code:

```
var a = '10',
    b = '20';

$("#block").animate({
    marginLeft: a + b
}, 500 );
```

Why it doesn't it work correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You are adding strings and the marginLeft gets set to `1020` instead of `30`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've got quotes around the numbers in your variable declaration you're making them strings. This makes `a+b`=`1020

Now you may also have the problem that your `marginLeft` needs to have a unit declaration (e.g. px).

So you should have `$("#block").animate({ 'marginLeft': (parseInt(a)+parseInt(b))+'px'}, 500 );`

Comment: Ah fair enough... I'm sure I've had an issue with it in the past. Anyway, that was only a maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
string + string = string
'10' + '20' = '1020'

number + number = number
10 + 20 = 30

string - (-string) = number
'10' - (-'20') = 30

number + string = string
10 + '20' = '1020'
```